# Javascript - AddEventListener on ajax.always()

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, addeventlistener

I have a list of categories of providers and providers loaded by ajax in a page and I added a checkbox beside each of them.

1. `When the ajax call is done`, I add an EventListener on each checkbox to deal with checked/unchecked.
2. I call get_dispos_fournisseurs `when I checked/unchecked a category`, because I need to reload the providers.

The problem is that my javascript isn't always called. Is it because my ajax isn't really done or because it is asynchronous ? If yes, how can I fix that ?

Thank you in advance :)

```
 xhrLoad_panneau = $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: path_to_load_panneau,
        data: "contexte=" + contexte ,
        success: function () {

            for (var i in fournisseurs) {

                  $(bloc_fournisseur).append("<input id='"+fournisseurs[i][15]+"' class='progi' categorie='" + fournisseurs[i][11] +"' distance='"+ distance_text +"' provider_name='"+fournisseurs[i][2]+"' name='fournisseur' type='checkbox' />");
                            $(bloc_fournisseur).append("<img class='progi-img' src='/assets/progi/calendrier.png' alt='progi' />");

    }).always(function(){
            get_dispos_fournisseurs();
    });


function get_dispos_fournisseurs(){

    var myFunction = function (event) {

        document.getElementById("btn-dispos").disabled = ($("input[name='fournisseur']:checked").length < 1) ? true : false;

        if ($("input[name='fournisseur']:checked").length > 5) {
            this.checked = false;
        } else {

            if (this.checked) {
                ids[this.id] = [this.getAttribute('provider_name'), this.getAttribute('distance')];
            } else {
                delete ids[this.id];
            }
        }
    };


    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('progi');
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        checkboxes[i].removeEventListener("change", myFunction, false);
        checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', myFunction, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: my best guess is that the code is having trouble finding `myFunction()` since it's nested inside of `get_dispos_fournisseurs()` -- can you try and move `myFunction()` out to the global scope?

Comment: @Doug it looks like `myFunction` is only called in its lexical scope from what I can see. Where do you see it called out of scope?

Comment: @Doug I tried it, but it doesn't change anything. I added some details to my question if it can help you.

Comment: @dgeare I started my comment with "my best guess" because that's all I had :) I was curious if promoting the scope of the function for the change events would help resolve the bug

Comment: @NoémieHarvey you could try dropping in some console.log() messages in success and always (maybe even get_dispos_fournissuers) to see when/how often each gets called

Comment: @NoémieHarvey where is `fournisseurs` defined?

Comment: @dgeare `fournisseurs` is defined in a js file, why ?

Comment: @NoémieHarvey was curious if it was also loaded asynchronously and possibly `undefined` (or empty) at the time the for loop happens

Comment: also, you seem to be missing a closing `}` on that for loop from what I can see

Comment: @dgeare the problem is really just the event `change`that is not always called on checkboxes.

Comment: when they're not functioning appropriately, can you inspect the attached event listeners in the chrome devtools and verify there are 0 listeners bound to the change event?

Comment: One bug I have spotted: `removeEventListener` doesn't actually do anything, since you are redefining `myFunction` on each function call. Try moving `myFunction` outside of the function scope and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: @dgeare I debugged in the console, when I loop on my checkboxes, the event listener "change" is added. but when I check the checkbox, nothing happens (some works, others don't so it's really confusing) ...